# writing in mongodb fails / node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use node.js to communicate with the mongodb-server. The send of the variables and the export of the function are working. The writing in the DB isnt and I can't find the error. It seems to be a problem with the insert, but i cant find it.....

**mongo.js**

```
exports.InsertDocument = function InsertDocument(tblname, OutUser, OutEmail, OutDate) {
    console.log("function InsertDocument called");
    console.log(tblname + OutUser + OutEmail + OutDate);
    var document = {tablename:tblname, out_user:OutUser, out_email:OutEmail, out_date:OutDate };
    db.collection('movements').insert(document, function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("data saved");
    db.close();
    });
}
```

**index.js**

```
/* POST home page. */
router.post('/create_movement', function(req, res) {
    var tblname = req.body.tablename,
        OutUser = req.body.out_user,
        OutEmail = req.body.out_email,
        OutDate = req.body.out_date;
        mongo.InsertDocument(tblname, OutUser, OutEmail, OutDate);
        res.send("succesfull");
});
```

**node.js console**

```
Example app listening at http://:::3005
Connection established to mongodb://localhost:27017/straff
function InsertDocument called
test234
POST /create_movement 500 317.042 ms - 954
```

**out of rest client**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"></head><body><h1>db is not defined</h1><h2></h2><pre>ReferenceError: db is not defined
    at Object.InsertDocument (D:\test1\mongo.js:26:2)
    at D:\test1\routes\index.js:17:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\test1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
    at next (D:\test1\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\test1\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\test1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
    at D:\test1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22
    at Function.proto.process_params (D:\test1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
    at next (D:\test1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
    at Function.proto.handle (D:\test1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:3)</pre></body></html>
```

Comment: I think you have to instantiate `db` in your **mongo.js** file.

Comment: Yes, like theamateurdataanalyst suggests... There doesn't appear to be a "db" variable defined at this scope.  Perhaps at the top of your mongo.js you need something like:

    var db = something;

Comment: I switched to mongoose and got it working now. thank you all

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you everything:

```
ReferenceError: db is not defined
at Object.InsertDocument (D:\test1\mongo.js:26:2)
```

You have to connect to your database, and add all the details into a variable called db.

Using Mongojs would be like:

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs(connectionString, [collections]);
```

You'll have to check the docs for the driver your using.

Comment: I switched to mongoose and got it working now. thank you all